# Flexbox display issue with second div when using center

Tags: html, css

I'm using flexbox to center align a div within a div. I'm adding a third div within the second div that I want underneath the second and to float to the right of the size of the second div. If I set it to float right, it's still being forced into the second div. How can I force it below the second div and float it right like below?

[image: what i'm trying to accomplish]

```css
.welcome {
  font-size: 2.3em;
  line-height: 1.15;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 600px;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.welcometxt {
  width: 450px;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: justify;
}

.linksect {
  width: 400px;
}

.cursive,
.infolink {
  font-family: 'Marck Script', cursive;
}

.infolink,
.infoarrow {
  color: #8d0700;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.infoarrow {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Marck+Script" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="w3-row w3-margin w3-container w3-white w3-padding-32">
  <p class="cursive welcome w3-center">Welcome to the Historic Players Playhouse, home of The Players, founded in 1911.</p>
  <hr class="w3-padding-large">
  <div class="welcometxt">
    <p>The Players is an organization of gentlemen dedicated to the preservation of amateur theater. Our members come from diverse backgrounds and locations but share a common interest in amateur theater. We welcome as members all gentlemen who wish to share
      in the camaraderie of The Players.</p>
    <div class="linksect">
      <a href="#" class="infolink">Read More</a> <span class="fa fa-angle-double-right infoarrow" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Side note: You don't need flexbox to achieve what you have there at all.

Comment: @vicbyte it was something I had used before that worked, so I just used it. What would your suggestion be?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```css
.welcome {
  font-size: 2.3em;
  line-height: 1.15;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 600px;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.welcometxt {
  width: 450px;
  display: flex; /* displays children inline */
  flex-direction: column; /* stacks children vertically */
  margin: 0 auto;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: justify;
}

.linksect {
  width: 100%; /* modified */
  display: flex; /* added */
  justify-content: flex-end; /* horizontal alignment, aligns them to the far right */
  align-items: center; /* vertical alignment / centering */
}

.cursive,
.infolink {
  font-family: 'Marck Script', cursive;
}

.infolink,
.infoarrow {
  color: #8d0700;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.infoarrow {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Marck+Script" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="w3-row w3-margin w3-container w3-white w3-padding-32">
  <p class="cursive welcome w3-center">Welcome to the Historic Players Playhouse, home of The Players, founded in 1911.</p>
  <hr class="w3-padding-large">
  <div class="welcometxt">
    <p>The Players is an organization of gentlemen dedicated to the preservation of amateur theater. Our members come from diverse backgrounds and locations but share a common interest in amateur theater. We welcome as members all gentlemen who wish to share
      in the camaraderie of The Players.</p>
    <div class="linksect">
      <a href="#" class="infolink">Read More</a> <span class="fa fa-angle-double-right infoarrow" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: perfect! Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `flex-direction: column;` to your `welcometxt`, change the width of `linksect` to `100%` and align its content to the right:

```css
.welcome {
  font-size: 2.3em;
  line-height: 1.15;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 600px;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.welcometxt {
  width: 450px;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: end;
  text-align: justify;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.linksect {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
}

.cursive,
.infolink {
  font-family: 'Marck Script', cursive;
}

.infolink,
.infoarrow {
  color: #8d0700;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.infoarrow {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Marck+Script" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="w3-row w3-margin w3-container w3-white w3-padding-32">
  <p class="cursive welcome w3-center">Welcome to the Historic Players Playhouse, home of The Players, founded in 1911.</p>
  <hr class="w3-padding-large">
  <div class="welcometxt">
    <p>The Players is an organization of gentlemen dedicated to the preservation of amateur theater. Our members come from diverse backgrounds and locations but share a common interest in amateur theater. We welcome as members all gentlemen who wish to share
      in the camaraderie of The Players.</p>
    <div class="linksect">
      <a href="#" class="infolink">Read More</a> <span class="fa fa-angle-double-right infoarrow" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need flex to take paragraph at the center, having already `margin: 0 auto;`

```
.welcometxt {
  width: 450px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

than:

```
.infolink {
float:right;
}
.linksect {
  width: 400px;
  float:right;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9dhw5zLp/
    }

Answer (score 1):

And heres the version free of flexbox, as you asked. Html stays the same as you posted :)

```
.welcome, .welcometxt, .linksect{
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.welcome {
  font-size: 2.3em;
  line-height: 1.15;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 600px;
}

.welcometxt {
  width: 450px;
}
.linksect {
  width: 400px;
  text-align: right;
}

.cursive,
.infolink {
  font-family: 'Marck Script', cursive;
}

.infolink,
.infoarrow {
  color: #8d0700;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.infoarrow {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```